# Concatenation of $.contents() elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I'm combining the use of a quicksearch function and highlighting function to show a query as highlighted to the user. I can highlight just fine, this is done by wrapping the found elements in a span:

```
Query: "examp";

<h4>This is an <span class="highlight">examp</span>le query</h4>
```

And this works wonderfully, however, before each of the next queries by the user, I need to remove the previously highlighted elements.

Current Highlight Function:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + match + "</span>";
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Currently I'm using a simple function:

```
function clearHighlights(className) {
    $('span.'+className).each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
    });
}
```

But when you run `$('selector').contents()` I end up with `["This is an", "examp", "le query"]`. Which breaks my highlighting function.

So is there a way to concatenate `.contents()`? Or a better way to run a highlighting function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fixes your issue, resetting  html of parent (removes useless line breaks):

```
function clearHighlights(className) {
    $('span.'+className).contents().unwrap().parent().html(function(){return this.innerHTML});
}
```

### DEMO